# Convert array of keys to associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of data like so

```
[
 'one', 'two', 'three'
]
```

I need to convert it like so

```
[
  'one' => 'one',
  'two' => 'two'
]
```

I found out about array_flip which gives me

```
[
   'one' => 0,
   'two' => 0,
   'three' => 0
]
```

What can I do from there? Any clean PHP way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`array_combine()` is the way to go

```
$a = array('one', 'two', 'three');
$output = array_combine($a, $a);
```

Answer (score 5):

use [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

array_combine — Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values

```
$a = array('one', 'two', 'three');
$a = array_combine($a, $a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) with the same array used for the keys and the values:

```
$array = [
 'one', 'two', 'three'
];

$new_array = array_combine($array , $array);
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/398092)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
     $arr = array('one', 'two', 'three');
     $result = array();
     foreach ($arr as $value) {
         $result[$value] = $value;
     }
     print_r($result);
?>
```